# Looping JS Function Until if or else Condition is Met

Tags: javascript

I have created a function that when called with certain parameters will play out and then either tell the  player they won or died based on the math. I have tested the function and it properly works, I set the parameters in the function calling so that the player would win and it displayed the win message alert. But if I increase the monster health to where the player will not win the first time the function is called, the function will not repeat itself as I tried to set up with the "else fight()" (as seen below).

My question is this, how to loop the function with the same parameters as before until the else or else if arguments are met?

Calling the function in HTML:

```
<a class="button" onclick="javascript:fight(8, 5, 1, 10, 3);">Test fight</a><br>
```

JS Function:

```
var playerHealth = 100;

function fight(monsterHealth, monsterDmg, monsterArmor, itemDmg, armorSts) {
 newPlayerHealth = playerHealth - monsterDmg / armorSts + 2;
 newMonsterHealth = monsterHealth - itemDmg / monsterArmor + 2;
 if (playerHealth <= 0) {
      alert('You died...');
 }
 else if (newMonsterHealth <= 0) {
      alert('You won!');
 }
 else
 {
 var newPlayerHealth =  playerHealth;
 fight(newMonsterHealth, monsterDmg, monsterArmor, itemDmg, armorSts);
 }
}
```

EDIT: Updated function and it says you win no matter how high the monster's damage or health is.

Comment: Your if condition will never be true: playerHealth = 100 so your player can never die. Also, when the function calls itself in the else if, isn't it just passing exactly the same values through?

Comment: You need to abstract the "damage" logic out of that function, and call it every time you need to "fight", that's what I think

Comment: thanks for the comments, I'll do some testing right now based on what you said.

Comment: So changed the function as seen above. It seems to repeat now, but the player wins every time, no matter how high the monster's damage or health. I believe it keeps defaulting the players health back to 100 every time it repeats the function. Know how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `playerHealth` was intialize inside function which was resetting players health to 100 in recursive call.

`newMonsterHealth` was also not persisted considering recursive calls.

```
  <html>
<head>
<script>
     var playerHealth = 100;

function fight(monsterHealth, monsterDmg, monsterArmor, itemDmg, armorSts) {

 playerHealth = playerHealth - Math.floor(monsterDmg / armorSts) ;
    console.log("player helath"+playerHealth);
 monsterHealth = monsterHealth - Math.floor(itemDmg / monsterArmor) ;
    console.log("monster helath"+monsterHealth);
 if (playerHealth <= 0) {
      alert('You died...');
 }
 else if (monsterHealth <= 0) {
      alert('You won!');
 }
 else fight(monsterHealth, monsterDmg, monsterArmor, itemDmg, armorSts);
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="button" onclick="javascript:fight(100, 40, 1, 10, 3);">Test fight</a><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

P.S. I removed your +2 logic (I won't understood why you were adding)

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to work! And the +2 logic was something I was experimenting with, but wasn't entirely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need for a **recursive function** that ends when certain condition will be met.

here is an example:

```js
function recursive(target, i) {
  target.innerHTML += '<br>' + i;

  console.log('index is', i);
  if(i > 100) {
    return target.innerHTML += '<br>' + 'END';
  }
    
  return recursive(target, ++i);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  recursive(document.getElementById('test'), 0)
});
```

```html
<h1 id="test"></h1>
```